# Where To Download Windows Server Core

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, download, iso-image, headless

I'm looking for a place to download *Windows Server Core* (possibly for free) for trying on a VM, to learn more about windows stuff, users, groups, services, and things like that in a headless manner. 
Is there a place where I can download the *Windows Server Core* iso and install it on VM?

Comment: Have you searched for "windows server core download"? Usually the first and second results both lead to Microsoft's official ISO downloads.

Comment: It sure seems to say "Installation options: Server Core: This is the recommended installation option" in that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the regular server ISO, then choose Server Core during installation

> The Server Core option is a minimal installation option that is available when you are deploying the **Standard** or **Datacenter** edition of Windows Server. Server Core includes most but not all server roles. Server Core has a smaller disk footprint, and therefore a smaller attack surface due to a smaller code base.

Emphasis my own.

There is no "Windows Server Core" product per-se.

More information about Server Core can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core